# Finding sum of a series

Tags: java, largenumber

In one of the problem(no.6) in the projectEuler.net website we have to find difference of square of the summation of n numbers and summation of squared numbers.It is very easy but I am not able to think that how to find this when the input is very large.

For e.g. when n=1000 my java program is giving me q weird answer which is in negative. So, can somebody help me how to get rid of this?

Sorry for not submitting my code. But in my code also I have used long data type but still it was getting overflow.

My code is as follows:

```
package projectEuler;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Problem6{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=input.nextInt();
        int n;
        long a,b;

        while(t-->0){
            n=input.nextInt();
            a=((n*n*(n+1)*(n+1))/4);
            b=((n*(n+1)*(2*n+1))/6);
            System.out.println("sigma n^3 is "+a);
            System.out.println("sigma n^2 is "+b);
            //diff=(((n*n*(n+1)*(n+1))/4)-((n*(n+1)*(2*n+1))/6));
            System.out.println((a-b));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are experiencing overflow, use use `long` or `BigDecimal`

Comment: No code shown,....but integer overflow,.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `n` a `long`, not just `a` and `b`.  Otherwise, the expression `(n*n*(n+1)*(n+1))/4` will overflow, before you even assign it to `a`.  This is because a `int * int` always gives an `int` result, even if the result of the multiplication is too big to assign to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

**int**: Maximum value is 2,147,483,647

**long**: Maximum value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

You are reaching the max integer value, so it's a overflow error.

> Use long instead int.

More information: [Java Basic Data Types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement does not fit any primitive data types you can use **[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)**, **[BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)** also